# how to set specific ip in websocket server?(node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I can set the port on the Web socket server as shown below.

```
const wss = new WebSocketServer({
  port: rrPort,
});
```

(I tried set with 'host' and 'path' but it doesn't work.)
Now I have to set specific ip on the Web socket server.
I have two LAN so also IPs.
I wanna set with one of IPs but I can't.
I can get web socket server ip with connected PC as shown below.

```
const ip = ws._socket.remoteAddress.slice(7);
```

Comment: @Alex could you tell me how to specify a IP at the websocket client?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ip when you create http server which you pass to WebSocketServer to use.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(...);

// this is where you set the ip to listen to
server.listen(8080, '192.168.0.1', function() {

});

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    port: 1234
});
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work well :( It can't change ip.